# Gridview showing up deleted datas

Tags: asp.net

I just display my uploaded file details in my GridView, so there will be only one row in my GridView - multiple files are not allowed.

When I delete that single row and try to upload a new file, it is showing 2 rows (the new file and the deleted file).

I already tried using `GridView.DataSource = null` and `GridView.DataBind()`.

Note: I've rebinded my GridView after the delete, but it still shows the deleted file.

```
protected void DeleteLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["name"] != null)
    {
        string strPath = Session["filepath"].ToString();
        System.IO.File.Delete(strPath);

        GridView2.Rows[0].Visible = false;
        Label8.Text = "";
        Session["filename"] = null;
        Button3.Enabled = true;
    }

    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You must remove it from the grid's `DataSource`.

Comment: i tried using gridview.datasource =   null and gridview.databind() but no change

Comment: where do you set the data-source to gridview ?? I can only see the **DataBind()**

Comment: @SrividhyaAbbai: That should work. You could also try to bind an empty DataTable: `GridView2.DataSource = new DataTable();
GridView2.DataBind();`

Answer (score 0):

In some cases I've had to do something like this:

```
//page level variable
bool refreshRequired = false;

protected void DeleteLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["name"] != null)
    {
        string strPath = Session["filepath"].ToString();
        System.IO.File.Delete(strPath);

        GridView2.Rows[0].Visible = false;
        Label8.Text = "";
        Session["filename"] = null;
        Button3.Enabled = true;

        refreshRequired = true;
    }

}

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(refreshRequired)
    {
        //whatever you to to set your grids dataset, do it here
        //but be sure to get the NEW data
    }
}
```

At the time of `Delete`, your grid is bound to the old data. When you change the data, you must rebind it to the new.