# Gridview showing data

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, gridview

I want to display data into the `gridview` from the `database`

But Currently there is no **data** into the table but it *still* showing the records from the table.

Below is my code:-

```
protected void DisplayGrid()
{
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("Select * from XXACL_PN_FLAT_STATUS_HIS", ObjPriCon);

    DataTable dtfillgrid = new DataTable();

    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dtfillgrid);
    GrdBookingStatus.DataSource = dtfillgrid;
    GrdBookingStatus.DataBind();
}
```

and on page_load

```
 DisplayGrid();
```

I tried from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300970/gridview-showing-up-deleted-datas) its related to `Session` but I dont have any session right now.

**Also I cross checked the database name, Table name and connection string**

**UPDATE**

I tried with `Open` and `close` like below but still it didn't worked

```
try
    {
        ObjPriCon.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("Select * from XXACL_PN_FLAT_STATUS_HIS", ObjPriCon);
        DataTable dtfillgrid = new DataTable();
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dtfillgrid);
        GrdBookingStatus.DataSource = dtfillgrid;
        GrdBookingStatus.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    finally
    {
        ObjPriCon.Close();
    }
```

Comment: *Currently there is no data into the table* . Maybe your table is not refreshed from last time that you have opened. Did you try to close and reopen table to view data?

Comment: @user2946329: No i didn't tried that, let me check

Comment: @user2946329: tried like updated in question but still it didn't worked

Comment: No. I mean that probably you have data in your table but you couldn't see them because you see the old table's data. I said refresh the table to make sure that it still is empty.

Comment: @user2946329: can you show it please ?

Comment: Show what ?? Just close the opened table in server explorer and reopen it by clicking **Show table data** to make sure that your table is empty or has data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100215/discussion-between-coder-and-user2946329).

Comment: @user2946329: in table it is not showing any data, but in the gridview it is showing data for the same table. I tried by reopening but i am able to view earlier data into the gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a research of many things, I manage to got the solution.

Actually in `Toad`.

> After executing the select query in the `Oracle`, the next step what I thought of was **COMMITING** after I executed my select query.

So when I checked after commiting, It worked for me.